# Getting the name of a table from an activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

How do I create a table after the user has inserted the title and then make modifications (add, delete and update rows) in that table? This is the code line I am not so sure about: + **private String DATABASE_TABLE = ListTitle.getStringListTitle();** I have an Activity (ListTitle) with a simple layout of EditText and a Button. I want the input to be the name of a table in the SQLite database. This activity directs to another activity (NewList). Here is the code of the activity:

```
public class ListTitle extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputListTitle;
private Button buttonNext;
private String stringListTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_title);
    initUI();
    setButtonNext();
}
private void initUI()
{
    inputListTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_list_title);
    buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next);
}
private void setButtonNext()
{
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!inputListTitle.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                ListTitle.this.stringListTitle = inputListTitle.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListTitle.this, NewList.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast noInput = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sie müssen einen Titel für die Liste eintragen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                noInput.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
public String getStringListTitle()
{
    return stringListTitle;
}
}
```

This activity (NewList) allows the user to make the modofications in the table he named in the previous activity (ListTitle). Here is the code of the another activity

```
public class NewList extends AppCompatActivity {

private WordPairDatabase wordPairDB;
private WordPair lastEntry;
private TextView titleLastEntry;
private EditText inputWord, inputEquivalent, lastWord, lastEquivalent;
private Button addButton, modifyButton, deleteButton;
private String stringInputWord, stringInputEquivalent, stringLastWord, stringLastEquivalent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_list);
    initDatabase();
    initUI();
    setAddButton();
    setLastEntryUI();
    setDeleteButton();
    setModifyButton();
}
private void initDatabase() {
    wordPairDB = new WordPairDatabase(this);
    wordPairDB.open();
}
public void initUI()
{
    titleLastEntry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_entry);
    inputWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_word);
    inputEquivalent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_equivalent);
    lastWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_word);
    lastEquivalent= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_equivalent);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    modifyButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_modify);
    deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
}
public void setAddButton()
{
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stringInputWord = inputWord.getText().toString();
            stringInputEquivalent = inputEquivalent.getText().toString();
            if (!stringInputWord.equals("") && !stringInputEquivalent.equals(""))
            {
                wordPairDB.addWordPair(new WordPair(stringInputWord, stringInputEquivalent));
                setLastEntryUI();
                inputWord.setText("");
                inputEquivalent.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                Toast noInput = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sie haben nicht alles eingetragen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                noInput.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
public void setLastEntryUI()
{
    lastEntry = wordPairDB.retrieveLast();
    if (lastEntry!=null)
    {
        titleLastEntry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lastWord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lastWord.setText(lastEntry.getWord());
        lastEquivalent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lastEquivalent.setText(lastEntry.getEquivalent());
        modifyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        titleLastEntry.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        lastWord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        lastEquivalent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        modifyButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
public void setDeleteButton()
{
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stringLastWord = lastWord.getText().toString();
            stringLastEquivalent = lastEquivalent.getText().toString();
            wordPairDB.deleteWordPair(new WordPair(stringLastWord, stringLastEquivalent));
            setLastEntryUI();
        }
    });
}
private void setModifyButton()
{
    modifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stringLastWord = lastWord.getText().toString();
            stringLastEquivalent = lastEquivalent.getText().toString();
            wordPairDB.modifyWordPair(new WordPair(stringLastWord, stringLastEquivalent));
            setLastEntryUI();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    wordPairDB.close();
}
}
```

And here is the class where I handle everything related to the database

```
public class WordPairDatabase {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private final String DATABASE_NAME = "wortlerner.db";
private final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private final String COLUMN_WORD = "word";
private final String COLUMN_EQUIVALENT = "equivalent";
private String DATABASE_TABLE = getLastCreatedTable();
private WordPairDBOpenHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;

public WordPairDatabase(Context context)
{
    dbHelper = new WordPairDBOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);

}
public String getLastCreatedTable()
{
    return lastCreatedTable;
};
public void open() throws SQLException {
    try
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }
}
public void close() {db.close();}
public void addWordPair(WordPair wordPair)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_WORD, wordPair.getWord());
    values.put(COLUMN_EQUIVALENT, wordPair.getEquivalent());
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
}
public void deleteWordPair(WordPair wordPair)
{
    String toDelete = COLUMN_WORD + "=?";
    String[] argument = new String[]{wordPair.getWord()};
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, toDelete, argument);
}
public WordPair retrieveLast()
{
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" ORDER BY "+ COLUMN_ID +" DESC LIMIT 1";
    cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToLast())
    {
        WordPair result = new WordPair(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
public void modifyWordPair(WordPair wordPair)
{
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" ORDER BY "+ COLUMN_ID +" DESC LIMIT 1";
    cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToLast();
    int lastID = cursor.getInt(0);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_WORD, wordPair.getWord());
    values.put(COLUMN_EQUIVALENT, wordPair.getEquivalent());
    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, COLUMN_ID+"="+lastID, null);
    cursor.close();
}
private class WordPairDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_WORD
            + " text not null, " + COLUMN_EQUIVALENT + " text not null);";

    public WordPairDBOpenHelper(Context c, String dbname, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(c, dbname, factory, version);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        lastCreatedTable = DATABASE_TABLE;
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: If your first question was answered, you should post a new question. If your question was not answered and you are truly editing the question, it should still contain much of the original content so that future visitors can understand the posted answers.

Comment: As Code-Apprentice said, it is not allowed to completely change your question after you have received an answer. If you have a new follow-up question, then ask a new question. Include a link to this one, if necessary, to provide context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DBOpenHelper class override the onConfigure method and call the onCreate method again. Like this

```
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

and in the onCreate method use a try catch like this

```
          try {
            final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
                    + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + COLUMN_ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_WORD
                    + " text not null, " + COLUMN_EQUIVALENT + " text not null);";
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Found exception: ",e.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a class variable in the database helper class, along with a retrieval method.

```
public class WordPairDatabase {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "wortlerner.db";
    private final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private final String COLUMN_WORD = "word";
    private final String COLUMN_EQUIVALENT = "equivalent";
    private String DATABASE_TABLE = ListTitle.getStringListTitle();
    private WordPairDBOpenHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private String lastCreatedTable; //<<<<<<

    public String getLastCreatedTable() {
        return lastCreatedTable;
    } ..........

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        lastCreatedTable = DATABASE_TABLE; //<<<<<<<<<<
    }
```

and then use the following to retrieve the table name

```
    String the_tablename = WordPairDatabase.getLastCreatedTable();
```

This does assume that you just want the last one created, which is how I interpret you question.

You could use this in two ways for example (possibly too inflexible):-

```
public void deleteWordPair(WordPair wordPair)
{
    String toDelete = COLUMN_WORD + "=?";
    String[] argument = new String[]{wordPair.getWord()};
    db.delete(lastCreatedTable, toDelete, argument); //<<<<<<
}
```

or you could use :-

```
public void deleteWordPair(WordPair wordPair, tableName) //<<<<<<
{
    String toDelete = COLUMN_WORD + "=?";
    String[] argument = new String[]{wordPair.getWord()};
    db.delete(tablename, toDelete, argument); //<<<<<<
}
```

along with :-

```
wordPairDB.deleteWordPair(new WordPair(stringLastWord, stringLastEquivalent),WordPairDatabase.getLastCreatedTable());
```

*(as used in the `setDeleteButton` method in the `NewList` class)*

*Note I haven't done any testing so there may be the odd error.*

#### Edit now that I think that I understand your question

As I understand your question now what you want is to get the users input from the **EditText inputListTitle** and use that in the **NewList** activity to then use it to create a table in your database.

Generally the accepted way of passing data to an invoked activity is via the Intent that is used to invoke the activity by adding IntentExtras.

These are relatively simple to use, you use the Intent's 'putExtra' method which takes two parameters. a) The data itself and b) a key to identify the data.

for example `yourintent.putExtra("myIntentKey","mydata");`

The has to be done after creating the Intent and before invoking the startActivity method.

You can use numerous IntentExtras.

In the started/invoked activity you then retrieve the IntentExtras using the key.

for example String mypasseddata = getIntent.getStringExtra("myIntentKey");

So to implement this :-

1) In the ListTitle activity change (add 1 line)

```
private EditText inputListTitle;
private Button buttonNext;
private String stringListTitle;
```

to

```
private EditText inputListTitle;
private Button buttonNext;
private String stringListTitle;
public String INTENTKEY_INPUTTITLE = "inputtitle"; //<<<<<<<<
```

---

2) Again in the ListTitle activity change

```
            ListTitle.this.stringListTitle = inputListTitle.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListTitle.this, NewList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
            ListTitle.this.stringListTitle = inputListTitle.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListTitle.this, NewList.class);
            intent.putExtra(INTENTKEY_INPUTTITLE,inputListTitle.getText().toString);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Note! `ListTitle.this.stringListTitle = inputListTitle.getText().toString();` is redundant so you can remove this unless (assuming that you have no intention of using `stringListTitle` elsewhere within the `ListTitle` activity). Additionally the `getStringListTitle` would then be redundant, so could also be removed, as could the declaration of the `stringListTitle` variable.

So steps 1 and 2 will pass the input(title) to the NewList activity.

3) In the `NewList` activity's `onCreate` method retrieve the intent.

After Line

```
        setModifyButton();
```

add

```
    String passsedLastTitle = getIntent.getStringExtra(ListTitle.INTENTKEY_INPUTTITLE);
    if (passedLastTitle.length() < 1) {
        // handle empty string for example
        finish(); // finish the activity and return to ListTitle
    }
    // String variable passedLastTitle = input from ListTitle
```

Assuming that you then want this value to be placed in to the **DATABASE_TABLE** variable in the **WordPairDatabase** class then:-

You should have a method in the WordPairDatabase class, a setter, to do this e.g.

```
public void setDatabaseTable(String newTableName) {
    DATABASE_TABLE = newTableName;
}
```

You could then invoke this from the `NewList` however not until after you have created an instance of a WordPairDatabase.

Additionally if your aim is to create a new table based upon the user input, I don't believe that this will happen. The only place that you appear to have code that creates a table, is in the `onCreate` method of the WordPairDBOpenHelper.

The `onCreate` method only automatically runs once only in the lifetime of the database file. i.e. it only runs when the database is created. It does not run every time you create an instance of the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass. As such you would need to create a method to create a new table. Such a method would/should take the table name as an argument.

Comment: I did the changes like you said, but the variable is still not received by the java class. The Exception I get is the following java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.ur.mi.wortlerner/de.ur.mi.wortlerner.NewList}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM null ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: I didn't make changes to use/implement the above. All I did was show you how to save the last table and how you can get the last table. In due course I will ad some example uses. Noting that they will not be tested.

Comment: However, this would not create the table before the insertion, right? should I pass the parameter to the DBOpenHelper as well?

Comment: Correct, I think I understand what you want now. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I am truly sorry if I am still missing something, please see the edit

Comment: As you said I need a method to create the table with the name as a parameter. Would you mind giving me an example of how to implement that in the inner WordPairDBOpenHelper class? Thanks in advance because that is what is causing me trouble